# Convert string date to datetime

Tags: c#

I have string contains date like this "Mar  8 1969 12:00AM" and I want to convert it to 03/08/1969

I tried

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.Parse("Mar  8 1969 12:00AM","MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt",CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
var stringdate = dt.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy").Split('/');
```

but it always crash giving the string doesn't represent a date

Comment: Your date doesnt match the format mm/dd/yyyy. You might need to write your own method to convert 'Mar' to '03', make the day two digits, and change the spaces to '/'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the method ParseExact

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss(v=vs.110).aspx

The problem with your string is that its not matching the provided/expected format.

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact("Mar 08 1969 12:00AM","MMM dd yyyy hh:mmtt",CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Answer (score 3):

This is what you need i believe:

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.Parse("Mar  8 1969 12:00AM", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
string stringdate = dt.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
```

You may also do this:

```
DateTime dt;
if(DateTime.TryParse("Mar  8 1969 12:00AM", out dt))
    string stringdate = dt.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"); //on success assign the value
```

The return value of `TryParse` indicates whether the conversion succeeded.

Answer (score 0):

DateTime.Parse does not accept a format string. You need to use [DateTime.ParseExact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), and have the second parameter correspond to the format of the given date string. It seems you would attempt to use the format "MM/dd/yyyy..." to parse "Mar  8 1969", but those formats do not match.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [DateTime.ParseExact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.parseexact%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), Note you have **two** spaces between `Mar  8`, once you parse the string to Date you can use ToString and give [Custom Date Format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) you want.

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact("Mar  8 1969 12:00AM", "MMM  d yyyy hh:mmtt", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
string dateString = dt.Date.ToString("MM/d/yyyy");
```